# Why can the code android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT can run correctly?

Tags: android

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
 adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, cur, cols, views,0); 
}else{ 
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, cur, cols, views); }
```

I think the code above will cause error because `adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, cur, cols, views,0);` can work only `API.sdk >=11` , now my app is `android:minSdkVersion="8"`, but the code is OK in the app, why? Normally the eclipse system will tell me `android:minSdkVersion` must be larger than 11 when compile.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're compiling against a `targetSdkVersion` greater than or equal to 11. The code will only be run on a device >= 11 because of the safety check, so no, you should have no issues with this code.